# Levels of a random effect coincide with values of covariates

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, ancova

My data are the wing area of insects, catched during the 12 years. Each year corresponds to one value of a mean ambient temperature, one value of rainfull and sample of the individuals. My task is the researching of temperature and rainfull (covariates) effects on the wing area (response) (there is another categorial factor too, but it is not important for my question). Individuals are grouped by years, then it seems appropriate to add in my model the "year" as a random factor with 12 levels:  `lmer(area ~ temperature*rainfull*categorial factor+(1|year), data=dt)`
But each level of a this random factor coincide with the corresponding value of a temperature and rainfull! Which way is the most correct in such situation? Is the addition of a random factor “year” recommended in this situation? If based on the AIC and BIC, the models with "year" as a random factor as a rule are better than without it.

Besides, the covariates residuals (due to a little number of covariates values) are non-gaussian, whereas  the response residuals are gaussian. Which type of model is recommended in such case?